# Where is the rest of my bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, wallet, electrum, change, bitcoin-wallet-app

I sent bitcoin from one of my wallets to another wallet using one address (output)
then this is what I got only a fraction of my bitcoin the bigger amount went to another unknown address to me

https://blockchain.info/tx/9ddc08fd1faf741bfa77a606d7b7faf8ba92dd2229fc7525e7e00c6f704e60e1

total newbie here don't even ask why I transfer from one wallet to another...
this was a transfer from electrum wallet to mybitcoin wallet if that matters
this is the first transaction from the first bitcoin I bought
there no new adres for my change in my wallet

Comment: just to clarify to make sure I can answer this properly (if I can), you intended to send how much Bitcoin from address `3BMSebkKfRjJcFGp3moofZ2oVnDaFp8hm6`? and to which address did you intend on sending it to, `1FAsfPJ5WCE6N9aqjzUqnuwEwEmLLzERru` or `1Apg8f9n2CawhNdVSyKUmRgigv8qXffJgy `? Feel free to ask questions if you need me to clarify mine.

Comment: I sent .00247311 from 3BMSebkKfRjJcFGp3moofZ2oVnDaFp8hm6 to 1FAsfPJ5WCE6N9aqjzUqnuwEwEmLLzERru only .00047311 went to 1FAsfPJ5WCE6N9aqjzUqnuwEwEmLLzERru and the other .002 shows to be sent to 1Apg8f9n2CawhNdVSyKUmRgigv8qXffJg, if that's acreated change where is it then because is no where to be found in my wallet and my balance is 0 on3BMSebkKfRjJcFGp3moofZ2oVnDaFp8hm6 and .00047311 on 1FAsfPJ5WCE6N9aqjzUqnuwEwEmLLzERru

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you did, what is the name of your wallet? are you using BitcoinCore, or the Blockchain.info wallet? it seems you're using CoinBase, I'd email them for help and more information, or go to their help center.